# Not Found: /post/12/responses/

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

What I am trying to do is to get particular post comments.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField()
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Home')
```

views.py

```
class CommentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Comments
    template_name = 'CovidHelp/comment_response.html'
    context_object_name = 'comments'
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Comments.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-date')
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/responses/', CommentDetailView.as_view(), name='responses')
```

However I'm getting error when trying to access such an url:

> Not Found: /post/12/responses/

Comment: Given code parts are inconsistent: `reverse('post-detail'` vs `path(... name='responses'`, URL for `post-detail` vs View for `CommentDetail`.

Comment: Are you sure the object exists in the database? `get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`

Comment: Even if full config is fine, the error is pretty clear: you don't seem to have post with pk=12 in the database. However it seems that config is broken and actually the code is trying to get Comment instance with id of the Post. Perhaps post with id=12 exists but comment with id=12 does not.

Comment: Show us your full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to return a list of comments for a post right?

so you need to use `Listview` instead of using detailview to return a list of comments and then use `get_queryset` to filter it by the post id.

Comment: Thanks i mistakenly added detailed view